# Showing trailing spaces in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I've set the following options in .vimrc

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,trail:·
set list
```

And expected to see dots in those places where spaces are used for tabulation in the code (I use spaces, not tabs).
However, the result is different:

[image]

Could you please recommend how to reach the desired result? Thanks!

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You should check [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces). I'm using the `match` command solution :

```
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
:match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

This page also provides [`list` based solutions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces#Using_the_list_and_listchars_options) which I haven't personally tried.

Comment: Thank. This is really what I looking for. But this match sometimes will be reset after doing some operations. How to always keep it on?

Comment: put in in your `.nvimrc`. without the colons

Comment: @Rocky You can use :2match {group} /{pattern}/

Comment: I would also recommend adding `autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()` as given in the linked page.  It helps prevent highlighting while in the insert mode.

Comment: note that it is important to place those lines behind your `colorscheme ...` command

Answer (score 13):

The [vim-better-whitespace](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace) plugin incorporates many tips from the [Vim Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) referenced in @icecrime's answer. It also has some nifty configuration options.

I installed [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) just to use this plugin and am happy with my life, all things considered.

Answer (score 7):

> And expected to see dots in those places where spaces are used for tabulation in the code (I use spaces, not tabs)

Actually this is the other way round, `tab` option is used to display a character when a tab character is inserted (\t) instead of spaces.
And `trail` is use to show trailing spaces at the *end of lines*.

You seem to have single empty line with trailing spaces, and dots are correctly displayed.

If you are only using spaces `tab` option is not used or displayed.

Answer (score 6):

To highlight trailing whitespace characters:

`:set hlsearch`, then

`/\s\+$`

Answer (score 3):

A more programmatic way to do this is via function [`matchadd()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchadd()):

```
hi TrailingWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red

call matchadd("TrailingWhitespace", '\v\s+$')
```

The 2nd paramter to `matchadd()` is the pattern we want to match. Here, we use single quote to avoid having to escape speical characters like backslashes etc, see also [literal-string](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#literal-string).

Comment: Using `matchadd()` is practically the only reliable way to always highlight. If quoting `:help match` it says:
_Highlighting matches using |:match| are limited to three matches (aside from |:match|, |:2match| and |:3match| are available). |matchadd()| does not have this limitation and in addition makes it possible to prioritize matches._

So to e.g. match both non-breaking spaces and trailing white-space, use: 
`highlight InvalidWhitespace guibg=red |
call matchadd('InvalidWhitespace', '\%u00a0') |
call matchadd('InvalidWhitespace', '[[:blank:]]\+$')
`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link posted by icecrime, I find this works quite well...

```
" Be clever about highlighting trailing whitespace (don't highlight it if we are
" in 'insert' mode and the cursor is at the end of the line). Also (regardless
" of 'insert' mode), highlight any tabs that immediately follow space(s).
" EOLWS and EOLWSInsert are colour group names; the latter being toned-down to
" make editing in 'insert' mode easier on the eye
autocmd InsertEnter * match EOLWS // | match EOLWSInsert /\s\+\%#\@<!$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd InsertLeave * match EOLWSInsert // | match EOLWS /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd WinEnter,BufWinEnter,WinNew * match EOLWS /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/

" Disable syntax-specific trailing space error handling because it conflicts
" with the above, mostly because the syntax highlighting doesn't take account of
" whether 'insert' mode is active or not. There are other '*_no_trail_space_error'
" settings - refer to syntax files in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/
let c_no_trail_space_error = 1
let java_no_trail_space_error = 1
```

Also, make sure the 'Error' highlight group is NOT defined as inverse video - if it is, it conflicts on strange ways with the above

Answer (score 0):

> And expected to see dots in those places where spaces are used for tabulation in the code

Vim has 3 options for displaying spaces with `listchars`:

- `space` show all spaces with the specified character.
- `lead` Shows *leading* spaces, i.e. spaces at the starting of the line. I think this is what you want.
- `trail` Shows *trailing* spaces, i.e. spaces at the end of the line.

There is also `multispace` but that is irrelevant to your problem.