# How to make two user-defined highlights work together

Tags: vim

I would like to highlight overlong lines in `Vim` (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/235970/1329844) as well as trailing whitespace (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617156/1329844). However, whenever I use both highlights, only the last one is applied.

I have the following code in my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=0 ctermfg=197
match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=0
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

When I open a file, only trailing whitespace is highlighted. If I exchange the order of the two highlight/match pairs, only overlength lines are highlighted. What do I need to change so that both patterns are matched and highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:match` command can only have one active pattern. If both of your highlights used the same colors, you could combine the patterns with `\|`. Here, you have to use one of the two alternative commands: either `:2match` or `:3match`, or you can use the (newer) `matchadd()` function, where you can specify arbitrary numbers (> `3`) as the (last) `{id}` argument.

```
:call matchadd('OverLength', '\%>80v.\+', 10, 4)
:call matchadd('ExtraWhitespace', '\s\+$', 10, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, Ingos solution is to be prefered, but nevertheless, you can use this:

```
:match MyCustomHighlight /\%(\s\+$\)\|\(\%>30v.\+\)/
:highlight MyCustomHighlight ctermbg=0 ctermfg=197
```